# CDC strategy for multiple staging tables

Tags: etl, data-warehouse, cdc

I'm implementing a Data Mart following the Kimball methodology and I have a challenge with applying deltas from multiple source tables against a single target dimension.

Here's an example of the incoming source data:

```
STG_APPLICATION
APP_ID, APP_NAME, APP_START_DATE, CDC_HASH, ...
1, FOOBAR, 20/10/2018, MD5_XXX

STG_APPLICATION_STATUS
APP_ID, STATUS_CODE, STATUS_DESC, CDC_HASH, ...
1, SUBMITTED, "APP WAS SUBMITTED", MD5_YYY
```

Each of these tables (there are several others) represent a normalised version of the source data i.e. a single application can have one or more statuses associated with it.

Now then, because we only get a full alpha for these tables we have to do a snapshot merge, i.e. apply a full outer join on the current day set of records against the previous day set of records for each individual table. This is computed by comparing the CDC_HASH (a concat of all source columns). The result of this comparison is stored in a delta table as follows:

```
STG_APPLICATION_DELTA
APP_ID, APP_NAME, APP_START_DATE, CDC_HASH, CDC_STATUS ...

STG_APPLICATION_STATUS
APP_ID, STATUS_CODE, STATUS_DESC, CDC_HASH, CDC_STATUS...
1, AWARDED, "APP WAS AWARDED", MD5_YYY,  NEW
```

So in this example, the first table, STG_APPLICATION did not generate a delta record as the attributes pertaining to that table did not change between daily loads. However, the associated table, STG_APPLICATION_STATUS, did calculate a delta, i.e. one or more fields have changed since the last load. This is highlighted by the CDC_STATUS which identifies it as a new record to insert.

The problem now of course is how to correctly handle this situation when loading the target dimension? For example:

```
DIM_APPLICATION
ID, APPLICATION_ID, APP_NAME, APP_START_DATE, APP_STATUS_CODE, FROM_DATE, TO_DATE
1, 1, FOOBAR, 20/10/2018, SUBMITTED, 20/10/2018, 12/04/2019
2, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, AWARDED, 13/04/2019, 99/99/9999
```

This shows the first record - based on these two staging tables being joined - and the second record which is meant to reflect an updated version of the record. However, as previously illustrated, my Delta tables are only partially populated, and therefore I am unable to correctly update the dimension as shown here.

Logically, I understand that I need to be able to include all fields that are used by the dimension as part of my delta calculation, so that I have a copy of a full record when updating the dimension, but I'm not sure of the best way to implement this in my staging area. As shown already, I currently only have independent staging tables, each of which calculate their delta separately.

Please can somebody advise on the best way to handle this? I'm scrutinized Kimball's books on this but to no avail. And I've equally found no suitable answer on any online forums. This is a common problem so I'm sure there exists a suitable architectural pattern to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to either compare on joined records or lookup the current dimension values.

If the amount of (unchanged) data is not excessive, you could join the full snapshots of STG_APPLICATION and STG_APPLICATION_STATUS together on APP_ID until they resemble the dimension record column-wise and store those in a separate table with their CDC hash to use as previous day. You then take the deltas at this level and send the (complete) changed records as updates to the dimension.

If the amount of records in the daily update makes it impractical to join the full tables, you can take the deltas and full outer join them as you do now. Then you look up the current dimension record for this APP_ID and fill in all empty fields in the delta record. The completed record is then sent as an update to the dimension.
This solution requires less storage but seems more fragile, especially if multiple changes are possible within a day. If there are many changes, performance may also suffer. For a handful of changes in millions of records, it should be more efficient.